# Generate word documents from excel file using mail merge

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to generate word documents using the mail merge feature in Microsoft Word.  To be as clear as possible my dream would be to:

(1) Place all values for all documents to be created in one excel document
(2) Use Word to create a template by selecting the above excel file as the data sheet
(3) Run a macro that would use the values from the excel sheet and perhaps the built in mail merge feature of Word to generate 1 file for each line in the excel sheet using one of the cells as the name of the file to be saved.

The end result would be the ability to create x number of Word documents using a template that pulls all the values from an excel sheet including the file name of the generated document.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean like this? http://www.codeforexcelandoutlook.com/excel-vba/automated-word-mail-merge-from-excel/

Comment: Otaku, can you explain what that does over and above Word's built-in Mail Merge features? Why does it need to split the XLS rows into separate files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using **Word and Excel Automation**, using languages such as Visual Basic 6 (through `COM`), VB .Net (through `interop`) or C# (through `interop`), for example for getting data from a database. In your case because you simply want to create a documente based on excel data the simplest manner is to use the MS Word **Mail's Merge Wizard**.

Take a look at:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/print-labels-by-using-excel-data-in-a-word-mail-merge-HP005203760.aspx